# Can an inner product on a vector space be negative?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

This may be a noob question but I recently read a definition that an inner product on a complex vector space is said to be a positive-definite sesquilinear map.

Doesn't positive definite mean that the inner product will only return positive values?

(Just started studying Functional Analysis specifically Hilbert Spaces)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Positive-definite in this sense only means that $\langle x, x\rangle > 0$ if $x \neq 0$, it doesn't prohibit general $\langle x, y \rangle$ from being zero, negative, complex, etc.

Comment: (+1) ... And sometimes not even real, depending on the vector space it is acting on.

Comment: @Eff especially on a complex vector space (as OP has cited) (+1)

Comment: Thanks for noting this, it's a good thing to include.